# jquery throws "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded "

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fancybox-2

I am using `FancyBox2-Rails` to open a small window/dialogue box when someone clicks on a certain link on my site.

Here is the simple view:

```
:javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.iframe").fancybox();
});

...

%li
  = User_name
  = link_to 'Click me', "http://www.google.com", :class => "iframe"

...
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded jquery.js:2868
jQuery.event.remove jquery.js:2868
jQuery.event.remove ....
.......
```

Could anyone tell me what's happening?

Thanks

Comment: Any chance you could throw the generated page into a fiddle?

Comment: Could you be more specific? (THere are a lot of source files ... I'm not sure which one(s) I should post here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens a lot lately, are you using twitter bootstrap?

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6862

Twitter Bootstrap 3.2 breaks Fancybox and fancybox support already said they won't fix it, so its mostly a javascript issue rather than rails

That's in the case you are using Twitter Bootstrap 3.2 or something like that

---

Follow the issue on the [github link](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6862), there seems there is a fix by doing

change code in line 794 (bootstrap.js)

```
.on('.dropdown-menu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
```

for this

```
.on('touchstart.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
```

Comment: On *dropdown.js*, replace
.on('.dropdown-menu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
with
.on('click.dropdown-menu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
Check the thread here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6862

Comment: I don't have such file as `bootstrap.js` in my project directory... So maybe this is not the problem. But thanks for the answer

Comment: Actually, I took that back. WHen I did `Inspect Element` from my broswer, the `bootstrap-dropdonw.js` file appeared in `Resources`. But it is read-only. How do I edit it?

Comment: You have to do the update on your source code, I'm not sure how are you loading twitter bootstrap into your app, perhaps you have it as a gem, but you can just download the .css and .js files from the twitter bootstrap and put it on your /assets directory, and then you can do the updates there.

Comment: Right, I am loading the bootstrap as a gem. (And I'm not sure why people want to do it that way, rather than just download the .css and .js files)